# Automate Windows Firewall "Restore Defaults"

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

I have several computers that are deployed in my network right now.  THey were deployed with a strange issue not allowing remote assistance.  The 'fix' is to click the "Restore defaults" link in the picture below (on the left sidebar)

I have the problem that happens everytime a machine is built using MDT, and I would like to have a fix that I can automate that would, after the build is done, apply the "Restore defaults" action.

Does anyone know where I should go to apply that particular action?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

reset
Restores Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to all of its default settings and rules. Optionally, it first backs up the current settings by using the export command to a configuration file. This command is equivalent to the Restore Defaults command in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security MMC snap-in.

Found it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1_reset